# MRTK v2, how do you make an object dragged by the pointer, stay straight out from the controller?

Tags: mrtk

In the MRTK v2 HandInteractionExamples.unity, when you drag an object with the controller, it acts like it is connected to a fishing line, where pointing the controller in a different direction curves the pointer line, and the object doesn't stay in front of the controller.

The Cliff House in Microsoft's MR Home, has the type of action I am trying to duplicate. You click on an object with the controller and drag it around. The object lags a little bit as it lerps to the new position, but it ends up straight out from the controller. How do I duplicate that control in the examples they provide?

I have made adjustments in a new profile I created, and have modified the DefaultControllerPointer code directly, but to no avail. I am not finding anything in the forums that has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5203, which is something that the MRTK team also observed in some internal builds. Looking at HandInteractionExamples in the latest code in the mrtk_development branch (as of 8/8/2019), this should be addressed.

See if you can grab the latest code from mrtk_development - this should make its way into a new release in the near future.

Comment: Thanks Will. The latest develop branch does "fix" the problem with some caveats, which I noted in the git issue you referenced in your answer.